# Restricting Responsive FileManager Folder With JS?

Tags: javascript, responsive-filemanager

I am using Responsive FileManager extensively as a standalone (not part of a general text editor). I sometimes call it multiple times on one page. However, each time I want it to be restricted to a certain folder—not merely so it defaults to a folder, but so the user can't navigate to any other folders at all.

The only way I have found to restrict a folder in Responsive FileManager is by setting the PHP sesssion variable:

`$_SESSION['RF']['subfolder']`

However, this is a problem for different folders that need to be there on the same page, and in general it's impractical because the restriction should be specific to the file manager call, not user-specific like a session. Also, I don't need it to be absolutely impossible to navigate to other folders in a secure way, it's OK if someone who knows how to use the browser debugger navigates somewhere else. I merely want to prevent casual users from doing this.

Is there any way to do this with a JS config option, or some other per-call and not per-user way?

Their feature list says:

> You can set a subfolder as the root and change the configuration for each user, page or FileManager call.

But I was not able to find a per-call folder restriction in their docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple tweak to achieve this .
Responisve filemanager calls the dialog.php with some parameters appended like type .What I did is :  introduce a new param and put a check  for that on the server side to set the uploads path dynamically .

Consider your uploads directory is ***uploads***
and you have ***user1*** , ***user2*** , ***user3*** as sub directories , So , in that case we will be setting the uploads path and current path in the **config.php** dynamically from the parameters which we will be passing while calling the **dialog.php**

In the filemanager/config/config.php 
Append these lines

```
if( isset( $_GET['MY_UPLOAD_PATH']))
 {
   $config['upload_dir']   =  $config['upload_dir'] . $_GET['MY_UPLOAD_PATH']."/" ;
   $config['current_path'] =  $config['current_path'] . $_GET['MY_UPLOAD_PATH']."/" ;
}
```

In the filemanager/dialog.php
Find this line
      **$get_params = http_build_query($get_params);**
And just before that line add

```
  if(isset($_GET['MY_UPLOAD_PATH'])){
     $get_params['MY_UPLOAD_PATH'] = $_GET['MY_UPLOAD_PATH'] ;
   }
```

Now change your variable

**$data['file_explorer'] = base_url('assets/resources/filemanager/dialog.php?type=0');**

to

```
 $data['file_explorer'] = base_url('assets/resources/filemanager/dialog.php?type=0&MY_UPLOAD_PATH=user1');
```

Just change the value of  the MY_UPLOAD_PATH param and the dialog.php will show only that particular directory .

Comment: While I am not keen on modifying the app, considering the future update issues it could cause, this seems like a simple enough solution that I might just use it. Thanks!

Comment: @Ynhockey Yes , its a quick fix and you can also make it more secure by managing a directory name to session loggedin user id relation so that instead of passing the parameter in the get request you can control it from session data